# Is it appropriate to copy a drawing from a book in my master thesis?

Tags: thesis, copyright, graphics

I would like to know if it is appropriate to copy a drawing from a book (specifically a directed graph) and develop my theory on that drawing? It is sure that I am going to make a reference for that drawing.

Note: The author of that book I intend to copy the drawing develops his theory based on that figure, but I am going to approach everything it matters more deeply.

Comment: Also see [Does copying the book's figure for my dissertation fit the copyright?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16107/does-copying-the-books-figure-for-my-dissertation-fit-the-copyright) and more generally, the [graphics+copyright](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics+copyright) tag search.

Comment: Also [Is it necessary to obtain permissions for copying figures from published articles in your proposal/dissertation?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4787/is-it-necessary-to-obtain-permissions-for-copying-figures-from-published-article)

Comment: Since the question is somewhat vague, it's hard to tell which of the many options is the most exact duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

Well, to my eye this is a good case of improving the state of the art, of course citing appropiately your sources. It is the same as quoting from a book.

On the other hand, if the *publisher* is especially nitpicking, maybe you could just use a software editor to re-create the drawing (still sourcing!) instead of using the "edited" drawing from a book.

Comment: It's not "nitpicking" for a publisher to require others to refrain from violating its copyright. And copying a figure is absolutely *not* "the same as quoting from a book" from a copyright perspective. Figures (unlike small sections of text) are considered works in and of themselves, so copying a figure is like copying an entire work (not a small part of it).

Comment: I'm not a publisher so I cannot say. Maybe I can reformulate the "especially nitpicking" to say your phrase, if it's more adequate.